# How to create an animation toggle in Qt?

Tags: qt, qpropertyanimation, qvariantanimation

I have a layout like this:
[image]

The requirement is When I click the button, the size of the `detailText` object will be enlarged/shrunken (BOTH CASES) as an animation.

This is my code:

```
#include <QPropertyAnimation>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->detailText->setVisible(false);
    connect (ui->button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::buttonClicked);
}

void MainWindow::buttonClicked()
{
    ui->detailText->setVisible(!ui->detailText->isVisible());
    ui->detailText->isVisible() ? ui->button->setText( "view less" ) : ui->button->setText( "view more" );
    runAnimation();
}

void MainWindow::runAnimation()
{
    QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation( ui->detailText, "size" );
    animation->setDuration( 1250 );
    if (ui->detailText->isVisible()) {
        animation->setStartValue( QSize( ui->detailText->width(), 0 ) );
        animation->setEndValue( QSize( ui->detailText->width(), ui->detailText->height() ) );
    }
    else {
        animation->setStartValue( QSize( ui->detailText->width(), ui->detailText->height()  ) );
        animation->setEndValue( QSize( ui->detailText->width(), 0 ) );
    }
    animation->start();
}
```

With this code, there are two problems:

1. When the `detailText` is invisible, and I click the button: the whole window is suddenly extended, and then there is animation for the `detailText`. I need the animation of the `detailText` makes the size of window larger accordingly. Or in another word, the enlargement of the whole window and the animation of `detailText` are synchronized.
2. The animation happens only one way: when `detailText` is invisible, I click the button, `detailText` will be shown and there is animation. But when `detailText` is visible, I click the button, the `detailText` is hidden, but no animation, the size of window is suddenly shrunken.

How should I correct my code?

My *.ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QWidget" name="">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>110</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>201</width>
      <height>161</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
     <property name="spacing">
      <number>0</number>
     </property>
     <item>
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="incon">
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>0</width>
           <height>0</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Icon here</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
         <property name="spacing">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <item>
          <widget class="QLineEdit" name="introText">
           <property name="text">
            <string>intro text</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QTextEdit" name="detailText">
           <property name="html">
            <string>&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd&quot;&gt;
&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;meta name=&quot;qrichtext&quot; content=&quot;1&quot; /&gt;&lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;
p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
&lt;/style&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body style=&quot; font-family:'MS Shell Dlg 2'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;&quot;&gt;
&lt;p style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;detail text. This is the detail text of the intro text.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;You can see this text when you click onto the button.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;Lorem Ipsum&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;Blablabla&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;1234&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;5678&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;Hello World&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="button">
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true"/>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>View more</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>400</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: How do you want to see the animation if you have hidden the widget?

Comment: @eyllanesc: Hi :). I have updated *.ui file and description of the problems above. Could you please read it again? Basically, what I need: when `detailText` is invisible, I click the button, there will be animation for `detailText`, the size of the `detailText` will be enlarged gradually, and this makes the size of the whole window enlarged accordingly **at the same time**. And when the `detailText` is visible, I click the button, there will be also animation for `detailText`, the `detailText` will be gradually shrunken, and it makes the size of whole window smaller also **at the same time**

Comment: @eyllanesc: Did I use the correct class for animation here?

Answer (score 0):

I think logic should be improved. In case your ui->detailText is visible, logically it should be like this:

```
animation->setStartValue( QSize( ui->detailText->width(), ui->detailText->height()));
animation->setEndValue( QSize( ui->detailText->width(), 0));
```

This would be because in case you detailText is visible, you already hide it instead of trying to shrink it to become invisible. And when it is invisible, you should probably try the following:

```
animation->setStartValue( QSize( ui->detailText->width(), 0));
animation->setEndValue( QSize( ui->detailText->width(), ui->detailText->height()));
```

In other words, the problem might be that you should change size of you widget you want to animate in a opposite direction than it is now. And finally, it would be very appreciated if you would provide *.ui file for your project, so we may be able to debug your code better, and see how it should be fixed. Currently, it is a bit of a wild guess, so I can not guarantee it will work for you.

Comment: thanks for your help. I have updated the *.ui file above. But in this case I think your logic is not really correct. `setStartValue` is the first value of animation, so in case `ui->detailText` is visible, the size of window would be enlarged a distance from 0 to the height of `ui->detailText`. And when the `ui->detailText` is invisible, the effect should be the other way around. When you test your code with my *.ui file, you will see the result. :)